# URL is getting splitted at "[" square bracket

Tags: java, android, url

This is a simple issue which I got stuck for hours now , the url is not taken completely, it is getting splitted as below:

[image]

This is what I am using in code:

```
  String Url1 = Myservice.S_DELETE_LIBRARY_BOOK+"["+bookData.get(position).getBookId()+"]"+"&libraryId="+LibId+"&userId="+Uid;

   //did encoding and decoding for testing
  try {
      Url1= URLEncoder.encode(Url1,"UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        Url1 = URLDecoder.decode(Url1, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  Log.d("LibraryAdapterUrl",""+Url1);
```

I also tried to encode and decode String but this did not work. I want the whole thing to be inside url.

```
[2]&libraryId=1&userId=4
```

That part is not considering as url,

I even pasted all URLs instead of `Myservice.S_DELETE_LIBRARY_BOOK`, still it is getting splitted at [2]

whole url is working fine in browser
.What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Why encoding URL with params? just encode param values

Comment: can you try `Myservice.S_DELETE_LIBRARY_BOOK+"\\["+bookData.get(position).getBookId()+"\\]"+"&libraryId="+LibId+"&userId="+Uid;`

Comment: You can do `URLEncoder.encode(Url1, "UTF-8");`

Comment: @MayurRaval i am getting  php?bookIds=\\[2\\]&libraryId=1&userId=4

Comment: @Redman, If you are see in the logs, it generally show url broken.. did you get the result ? or that link hit that api on server ?

Comment: no result is not working

Comment: @Redman, Have check it with debugger ? on `Log.d("LibraryAdapterUrl",""+Url1);` what exact `Url1` return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encode only the query string after the question mark

```
String url = Myservice.S_DELETE_LIBRARY_BOOK + "?xxx=" 
       + URLEncoder.encode("[" + bookData.get(position).getBookId() + "]", "UTF-8")
       + "&libraryId="  + LibId + "&userId=" + Uid;
```

Should the `[` need to be part of the site URL, then you are out-of-luck, that is illegal.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of this, why do not you use below approach:

```
String test = "http://<ipaddress>/"+URLEncoder.encode("yourArrayValue", "UTF-8") + "&libraryId="  + LibId + "&userId=" + Uid;
```

Or

```
public class HttpClientTest {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
            List<NameValuePair> qparams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("query1", "query1Value"));
            qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("query2", "query2Value"));
            qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("query3", "query3Value"));                
            URI uri = URIUtils.createURI("http", "www.google.com", -1, "/search",
                                         URLEncodedUtils.format(qparams, "UTF-8"), null);
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);
            System.out.println(httpget.getURI());
            //http://www.google.com/search?query1=query1Value&query2=query2Value&query3=query3Value
        }
        }
```

Comment: i have to add arraylist near bookIds

Answer (score 1):

You can handle this.

suppose you Pass the url value like below. (URL has braces in it)

MyLandingURL=url>http://www.dumyurl.co.uk/[2]stackoverflow

Then the below code will split and collect the url in array which is after > symbol. The code identifies what ever is there after >(greater than symbol) it is the full URL. So there is no chance the braces obstruct your code.

So you end up collecting the string 
**http://www.dumyurl.co.uk/[2]stackoverflow**

```
public String readURLor(String URLidentity) throws Exception {

    String locator = properties.getProperty(URLidentity);

    // Split the value which contains locator type and locator value
    String URLType = locator.split(">")[0];
    String URLvalue = locator.split(">")[1];

    if (URLType.toLowerCase().equals("url"))
        return URLvalue;
    else
        throw new Exception("URL Type '" + URLType + "'is not defined in OR file!!");
```

Comment: i dont want to split url, i want to join url

Comment: It doesnt split the url. The actually identifies what is the exact url you are passing. 

So the code collect the url in this way.

URLType = URL        and      
URL value = http://www.dumyurl.co.uk/[2]stackoverflow

Comment: I just edited my answer with little more explanation.